# Hardware to measure data usage of router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I want to measure the data usage through my router. I know this can be done using the router software but this is not an option for me. I want to connect a device between the internet aerial and the router.  The device should have one ethernet input and one ethernet output.

aerial >> ethernet cable >> device >> ethernet cable >> router >> laptops, mobiles, PCs

The device should just be a throughput of the signal. I want to be able to view the data usage on the device for set time periods, e.g. last 2 hours, today, last week. Does such a device exist?

Comment: I think those who've voted to close this haven't understood the question. The OP just doesn't know what type of devices are capable of doing what is needed. This person doesn't seem to be asking for shopping recommendations. Try not to imply the follow up question. The question asked will not likely be obsolete any time soon.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek I am not looking for a shopping recommendation. I just want to know what type of devices can solve my problem.

Comment: That would be me, and I'm *pretty* convinced its a shopping rec. I don't see myself reclosing the question if you guys could put in a question on meta asking for a reopening, and 5 users with permissions or another mod disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most home routers support some sort of rudimentary traffic meter. There is nothing stopping you from putting a router between the ISP supplied router and the rest of your network. You would then be able to use the new router to meter your traffic as long as it was the only thing plugged into the old router.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a smart switch of some sort, but then you will still use the software within that switch. May I ask why using the router software is not an option? It sure seems to be the easiest way to measure this.

Comment: The router was provided by my ISP and they will not provide me with the username and password.

Comment: Do you mean a network tap? They seem fairly expensive.